# Why is sub class' static code getting executed?

Tags: java, constructor, static, static-methods

I have written the following code and created object for the super class.

```
class SuperClass{
    static int a=2;
    static int b(){
        return 2;
    }
    int c(){
        return 2;
    }

    SuperClass(){
        System.out.println("Super");
    }
    static {
        System.out.println("super");
    }
}

public class Sub extends SuperClass{
    Sub(){
    System.out.println("Sub");
    }
    static {
        System.out.println("sub");
    } 
    static int b(){
        return 3;
    }
    int c(){
        return 3;
    }
    public static void main(String ax[]){
        SuperClass f =new SuperClass();
        System.out.println(f.c());
        System.out.print(SuperClass.b());
    }   
}
```

When I checked the output, it is as follows:

```
super
sub
Super
2
2
```

I know that static block is executed only when object of the class is initialized or any static reference is made. But here, i did not make any of these to Sub class. then why do i see "sub" i.e. sub class' static block output?

Comment: Executing the `main` method (which is nested in the `Sub` class) is a static reference. :)

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov I thought about that, but even then "sub" should come first right. Now, that doubt is cleared from Bathsheba 's answer as  static blocks are executed in the order of super and sub classes. Thank you.

Comment: @anil not first, the `Sub` class still depends on the `Super` class, which is therefore executed first.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> I know that static block is executed only when object of the class is initialized or any static reference is made. But here, i did not make any of these to Sub class.

**Your** code doesn't, but in order for that `main` to run, `Sub` has to be loaded. So the static initializer for it is run.

E.g., I'm assuming you ran it like this:

```
java Sub
```

The `java` tool has to load `Sub` to call `Sub.main`. That's the static reference (access, really) causing the static initializer to run. (If you ran it in an IDE, the IDE will do the `java` tool part, but the result is the same.)

So here's what happened:

1. `java` triggers load of `Sub`
2. JVM has to load `SuperClass` in order to load `Sub`
3. So we see their static initializers run, in order (`SuperClass`, then `Sub`):

   ```
   super
   sub
   ```
4. `java` tool calls `main`
5. Code in `main` calls `new SuperClass`:

   ```
   Super
   ```
6. Code in `main` calls `f.c()`

   ```
   2
   ```
7. Code in `main` calls `SuperClass.b`:

   ```
   2
   ```

As [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) helpfully [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150847/why-is-sub-class-static-code-getting-executed/35150945?noredirect=1#comment58026289_35150945), this is covered by the JVM specification in [§5.5 - Initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5) and the related [§5.2 - Java Virtual Machine Startup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2):

> Initialization of a class or interface consists of executing its class or interface initialization method (§2.9).
>
> A class or interface C may be initialized only as a result of:
>
> - ...
> - If C is a class, the initialization of one of its subclasses.
> - If C is a class, its designation as the initial class at Java Virtual Machine startup (§5.2).

That second-to-last bullet point covers `SuperClass`, and the last bullet point covers `Sub`.

Answer (score 12):

Because your `main()` method is a member of `Sub`, that class needs to be loaded for your program to run.

Answer (score 9):

In calling `main`, all the static initialisers are called, first in the super class, then the sub class.

That explains the output you observe.

Answer (score 3):

static blocks are run when the class is loaded. usually that is because you call a constructor or static member. in this case, it is because you executed the main method (a static member).

side notes:

1. another edge case is calling Class.forName(className) to load a class.
2. you may also notice that the base class is loaded before the subclass.